# (pandas) access all rows except for the first 3 for the specific columns at index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I want to access all rows except for the first 3 for the specific columns at index  1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14 of a csv file. How can I do this? All examples I have found show how to slice (for example 1:14 but I do not want all columns in between but specific ones.

When I try:

```
   p = df[3:, [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14]]
```

I get an error:

```
    p = df[3:, [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14]]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2139, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2146, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1840, in _get_item_cache
    res = cache.get(item)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

and   it does not work with the notation     `p = df[[3:], [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14]]`

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you need [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for filter by positions here all rows without first 3 and columns names by positions:

```
df.iloc[3:, [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p = df.iloc[[3:],[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14]]
```

you were mostly right except you just had to close the square brackets after "3:".
and using loc, iloc is recommended for indexing.

Comment: Can you explain importance `[3:]` here?

Comment: @jezrael, [3:] is used because the question mentions all rows except the first three,
so we start at 4th row, rows are indexed as 0,1,2,3...

Comment: I think why is beter use `[3:]` instead `3:` ?

Comment: df.iloc[[3:], [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14]] -> does not accept the format